# Cloning an Azure Subscription or Resources using Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-resource-manager, azure-resource-group, infrastructure-as-code

I am about to begin implementing several changes to an Azure Subscription in our Production environment, but also have the added benefit of having a "Dev" Azure Subscription to develop and test out all pending changes before committing them to the Production subscription. I am using Terraform/Powershell to implement all such infrastructural changes.

To facilitate my dev and test activities, what I'm therefore seeking to do is replicate or clone the entire Prod subscription (or in the worst case, some Resource Groups) in my Dev subscription.

Would therefore appreciate some suggestions on how to achieve this properly and safely.......with Terraform and/or Powershell only.

Answer (score 0):

Terraform deploys resources based on the `.tf` file, you could just copy the related `.tf` files to another directory to run terraform init, plan, apply in the Production environment.

The key point is that you should design your working workspaces with one or more accounts before working on it.

You may reference this blog---[Terraform With Multiple Environments](https://www.codurance.com/publications/2020/04/28/terraform-with-multiple-environments)